# serving files to a route without using path file in url on Express

Tags: express, routes

I'am serving files to my localhost on Express with this :

```
app.use(express.static('../../StockChart/'))

//StockChart is a dir which contains more dirs and files.
```

With this I can serve the files I want by simply writting down the path on the url , like :

```
http://localhost:3000/HomePage/HomePage.html
```

But what If I want to serve this same file (with CSS and JS files linked to it) , only to another route like : "/"  ?

I tried this :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("C:/Users/Simon/Desktop/Portfolio/Learning Projects vanilla JS/StockChart/HomePage/HomePage.html")
})
```

This only sends HTML and not the JS and CSS linked files.

What can/should I do to serve the files to the specific route.

I followed the express documentation on this link : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so one of the possible solutions I found that it works for now is to simply redirect the user to the intended page , like so :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.redirect("/HomePage/HomePage.html") })
```

It doesn't serve the pages to the pretended route but it redirects the user to the pretended page If he types the specific path.